# mgp25 - Whatsapp ChatAPI "bad_token" bug

Tags: php, whatsapp

I've googled this to death...

Am doing the initial “codeRequest”.
Cannot get past "bad_token".

I’ve checked all the values and tried all the versions/ classesMd5 I can find. Have also downloaded the  APK myself and calculated the MD5.

I’m just wondering if WhatsApp have completely changed the token algorithm or something? If anyone actually has this working I’d love to hear from you!

```
token.php

$waPrefix   = "Y29tLndoYXRzYXBw";
$signature  = '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';

//$classesMd5 = '14w/wF67XBf2vTc+qALwKQ=='; // 2.16.148
//$classesMd5 = '1I2weuZmVg+uL50+HXeSJw=='; // 2.16.328
//$classesMd5 = 'ry9Xz6kVioQctwA3G9z62Q=='; // 2.12.556
//$classesMd5 = 'IdHZifpmNTVVCJ50Cu7RMA=='; // 2.17.350
$classesMd5 = 'uxy2TKugqw984dWE55M7fw=='; // 2.16.24

$key2 = base64_decode('eQV5aq/Cg63Gsq1sshN9T3gh+UUp0wIw0xgHYT1bnCjEqOJQKCRrWxdAe2yvsDeCJL+Y4G3PRD2HUF7oUgiGo8vGlNJOaux26k+A2F3hj8A=');
```

and

```
Constants.php

const DEVICE = 'armani';                                                                 
const WHATSAPP_VER = '2.16.24';                                                              
const OS_VERSION = '5.1.1';
const MANUFACTURER = 'OnePlus';
const BUILD_VERSION = 'YOG4PAS3JL';
const PLATFORM = 'Android';                                                                  
const WHATSAPP_USER_AGENT = 'WhatsApp/2.16.24 Android/5.1.1 Device/OnePlus-A0001';
```

I'm pretty sure these are the relevant values, primarily:
WHATSAPP_VER, WHATSAPP_USER_AGENT and $classesMd5

Can anyone help?
Thanks

Comment: Can i know where you where you download the latest chat-api? Cause my constants.php seen diff with yours.

Comment: I updated my Constants.php with a mixture of values I got from various searches.
WHATSAPP_VER and WHATSAPP_USER_AGENT need to work together but the others I think don't do much.

That said, support for this API has ended and WhatsApp could disable it easily so I'd recommend not using it. I'm looking for a different solution.

Answer (score 1):

Tried it this morning and it's working now.

Maybe I triggered some kind of block yesterday while testing.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this one and I got the code by SMS

constants.php

```
const DEVICE = 'oppo';                      // The device name.
const WHATSAPP_VER = '2.18.154';            // The WhatsApp version.
const OS_VERSION = '5.1.1';
const MANUFACTURER = 'oppo';
const BUILD_VERSION = 'A37fEX_11_171209';
const PLATFORM = 'Android';                 // The platform name.
const WHATSAPP_USER_AGENT = 'WhatsApp/2.18.154 Android/5.1.1 Device/oppo-A37f';
```

token.php

```
$classesMd5 = 'LzjhvO17H+9KeBTuY363Ow=='; // 2.18.154
$key2 = base64_decode('eQV5aq/Cg63Gsq1sshN9T3gh+UUp0wIw0xgHYT1bnCjEqOJQKCRrWxdAe2yvsDeCJL+Y4G3PRD2HUF7oUgiGo8vGlNJOaux26k+A2F3hj8A=');
```

Answer (score -1):

After 9 Hours of R&D, Finally Got the Fruitful Results. Changes are on `ClassessMD5`

```
    public const string WhatsAppVer = "2.18.154";
    /// The port that needs to be connected to
    public const int WhatsPort = 443;
    public const string Device = "Android";
    /// manufacturer
    public const string Manufacturer = "Xiaomi";
    /// OS Version
    public const string OS_Version = "5.1.1";
    public const string UserAgent = "WhatsApp/2.18.154 Android/6.0 Device/Xiaomi-HM_1SW";


string token = "PdA2DJyKoUrwLw1Bg6EIhzh502dF9noR9uFCllGk1447796090073" + number;
var classesMd5 = "LzjhvO17H+9KeBTuY363Ow=="; // 2.18.154
```